# Connecting to public Redshift DB from Lambda with no VPC

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

On AWS, I have an API Gateway setup that calls a lambda function which in turns accesses a Redshift database.  All of these services are within the same VPC and work.  The only problem is that every api call takes a minimum 10 seconds just for spinning up the Lambda function inside a VPC.

From what I've read, if we were to move the Lambda function outside of the VPC it should be able to avoid that 10 second startup. However, is it still possible to connect to the redshift db at that point?  The redshift db is publicly accessible but does the lambda function need a VPC in order to access the internet/public redshift db?

Comment: When the lambda function is invoked for the first time, it boots up the code and that causes bit of delay. But after that it should be quick unless lambda is not called again for long time. I am not sure how can this be fixed by moving lambda out of VPC. Can you share the source of knowledge which recommends this?

Comment: Are you sure the overhead occurs for _every_ invocation?

Comment: Sure thing, this link explains it well https://medium.freecodecamp.org/lambda-vpc-cold-starts-a-latency-killer-5408323278dd . Specifically the line 'It’s interesting to note that, over all the data points, adding a VPC increased cold start times by an average of 8.83s'

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, yes even several calls made within seconds of each other after the point we'd expect the lambda to be up and spinning and no longer requiring a cold start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out i was having a timeout issue for the lambda connecting to the redshift db because the zone in the VPC that the redshift db lives in didn't have an IGW route table associated to it.  I fixed that and then all I had to do was remove the lambda from its vpc and things just worked.

Long story short: Make sure your redshift db has public internet access.

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested in comments, I would say, look into your Lambda code and see if the dependencies are really complex that it takes so much time in initialization.
I far as I understand, its going to take same time irrespective of its inside the VPC or outside.

There is something call as "Cold start / warm call with AWS Lambda", its time when initialization is taking place. As initialization requires building downloading the code, making container up, initializing the container and eventually executing the code.

Its nicely explained here.

https://blog.octo.com/en/cold-start-warm-start-with-aws-lambda/

"The initialization time of a Lambda represents a significant part of the total time. After a cold start, the Lambda will remain instantiated for a while (5 minutes) allowing any other call not to have to wait for this initialization to be done each time."

Regarding your second question, should you put Lambda outside, so the best practice suggests that "don't put Lambda inside the VPC unless you have to".

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html

Comment: Right, these are the links I've seen as well.  I guess my main question is if I need to put Lambda inside a VPC to connect to Redshift.

Comment: OK, I haven't tried outside VPC setup myself, I suggest you to give it a try. Logically, it should work. Meaning if your `Redshift` is publicly accessible from any IP address, then it must be accessible from `Lambda` as well unless your `Lambda` is blocked to make `outbound` connection on the `Redshift` `port` and `protocol`  because of other `security` settings.